# Can I have multiple dataLayer variables on the same page?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a website with GTM "client-side" implemented. In the current container, a lot of specific code have been written, related to the current "dataLayer" variable structure.

**On top of that**, I need to set up a "server-side" container with a "dataLayer" which has a completely different structure.

I planned to use 2 variables (ex: "dataLayer" and "dataLayer2"), and feed my GTM - respectively client-side and server-side - with it.

Google documentation state that I can rename the dataLayer (https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/datalayer#rename_the_data_layer),
so nothing is stopping me to give the right variable to the right container, but will it work ?

I also read articles on Simo Ahava's website, but I couldn't find any answers...

Thanks for your insights !

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the push into the same data layer object? What do you mean exactly by On top of that, I need to set up a "server-side" container with a "dataLayer" which has a completely different structure

Comment: I can mix the 2 structures in the same data layer object, but I'd rather not. These objects are quite large and the new structure is imposed. The current structure is already in place for the client-side GTM, the new structure is for the server-side GTM.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment